# Assigning primitives to NSManagedObject instance (Swift)

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-data, primitive, swift2

I am not able to make this work in storyboard:

#### Setup

```
// Extract an int from a (JSON) dictionary
let dict = ["eventId" : NSNumber(int:20)] as [String: AnyObject]
let eventId = dict["eventId"] as? Int

// Create managed object class
@objc(Event)
class Event : NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var eventId: Int16 // as generated by Xcode
}
var event = Event()
```

#### Trying to assign a primitive to a Core Data object fails

```
event.eventId = eventId! 
// Cannot assign a value of type 'Int' to a value of type 'Int16' 

event.eventId = Int16(eventId!)
// Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.

event.eventId = Int32(eventId!)
// Cannot assign a value of type 'Int32' to a value of type 'Int16'
```

#### Sanity tests

```
eventId == nil  // false
eventId == 0    // false
eventId!        // 20
Int32(eventId!) // 20, transforming into Int32 seems to work
Int16(eventId!) // 20, transforming into Int16 seems to work
eventId is Int  // true, but with weird warnings:
// Conditional cast from Int! to Int always succeeds
// 'is' test is always true
eventId is NSNumber // true, to my surprise! Only one warning:
// 'is' test is always true
```

#### More details

Note that casting the dictionary object to `Int16` or`Int32` returns `nil`.
Also, using `let eventId = dict["eventId"]!.integerValue` has the same results.
Defining the id as `Int32` does not help either, the assignment fails.

This happens the same way in a proper project with full Core Data stack, including model, context, etc.

I have a hunch that it has to do with the way the instruction `@NSManaged` generates the accessors, but I do not know how to fix it without writing tons of more code.

Also, when I sometimes create a new project with Core Data from scratch it just works - but I cannot discern any differences. Let me know if you have any insights. My usual workaround is to not use primitives, but using NSNumber is sometimes less concise.

Answer (score 1):

Instances of `NSManagedObject` *must* be created with the designated 
initializer

```
init(entity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:)
```

otherwise the Core Data accessor methods will not be created properly at runtime.
So this should work:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Event", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
let event = Event(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

// Alternatively, use the equivalent "convenience method" from NSEntityDescription:
let event = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Entity", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Event

event.eventId = Int16(eventId!)
```